# Ordering Matrix by Specific Column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using a relatively new version of Power BI for Report Server.

I have this simplified data:

```
ImaginaryData = 
DATATABLE (
    "Fruit", STRING,
    "Colour", STRING, 
    "Amount", INTEGER, 
    { 
        { "Apple", "Red", 10 }, 
        { "Apple", "Green", 5 },
        { "Apple", "Blue", 17 },
        { "Pear", "Red", 100 },
        { "Pear", "Green", 65 },
        { "Pear", "Blue", 5 },
        { "Orange", "Red", 12 },
        { "Orange", "Green", 8 },
        { "Orange", "Blue", 38 }
    } )
```

I then create a Matrix of the data:

[image]

I want to order this Matrix by amounts in the Blue column i.e. the Fruit Orange should be at the top of the list.

With a Table visual I hover over a column header and can then order by that column but that functionality does not appear for a Matrix.

How do I workaround this issue? [using a Table is not a solution]

Comment: Tricky, why can't you just use a table?

Comment: @StelioK because in the real report I am using the Month column from the Calendar table across the top

Comment: you can hack it. Create a rank for that blue column, ensure it starts at a number greater than the max value in all columns and sort by that, you'd have to hide that column but it might work.

Comment: @StelioK I don't think that will work

Comment: It will work :) you have to believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a sortcolumn to your table, that holds the sum of the blue amounts for that particular fruit. Like this.

[image: table]

You cannot do this in DAX (calculated column), because then you can't sort [Fruit] by [Sort], because [Sort] is allready indirectly sorted by [Fruit].

So you need to use the Query-editor. I recreated your table in an excel-workbook to import it. Then I used the following M script

```
let
    SortColour = "Blue",

    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\ImaginaryData.xlsx"), null, true),
    ImaginaryData_Table = Source{[Item="ImaginaryData",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ImaginaryData_Table,{{"Fruit", type text}, {"Colour", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),
    JoinTable = Table.SelectRows(Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Fruit", "Colour"}, {{"Count", each List.Sum([Amount]), Int64.Type}}), each ([Colour] = SortColour)),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"Fruit"},JoinTable,{"Fruit"},"SortTable",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded SortTable" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "SortTable", {"Count"}, {"Sort"})
in
    #"Expanded SortTable"
```

After loading this query, you can sort [Fruit] by [Sort] in the Data view (Sort by Column on the Modeling tab). Then  recreate the matrix visual and sort the Fruit Column descending by clicking the triangle in the visual.

[image]

When you add row { Pear / Blue / 50 } to the table in excel and refresh in PowerBI, the matrix changes to this:

[image]

Comment: this is very interesting - it is not going to be dynamic i.e. if the user hits a slicer etc. but it is better than nothing. I am using SQL-Server as my source so I'll add in this column at that source rather than M

Comment: happy with this approach - hopefully future iteration of the matrix will have this functionality included